# Android moving a shape faster on Canvas

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, android-drawable

I have a class which is extended from ImageView (lets call it '**surface**'). On onDraw method, a little dot is drawing on canvas. When I click a button I try to move this dot to another location. You can consider like manual version of translate animation. It works but now I try to figured out speed of this moving. I mean I want dot moving faster.

Relevant part of **surface** :

```
private float actual_x=100,actual_y=100; // Dot is drawn on 100,100 at beginning
private float increase_x,increase_y;
private boolean isMovingResume=false;
private int moving_counter;

public void changeLocation(float x,float y){
    isMovingResume=true;
    moving_counter=0;
    increase_x=(x-actual_x)/50;
    increase_y=(y-actual_y)/50;
    invalidate(); // This trigger onDraw method
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(actual_x,actual_y,15,fill_paint);
    if(isMovingResume){
        actual_x=actual_x+increase_x;
        actual_y=actual_y+increase_y;
        if(moving_counter==49){  // Moving will end after 50 redraw
            isMovingResume=false;
        }
        else{
            moving_counter++;
        }
        invalidate(); //redraw
    }
}
```

And my button click :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        surface.changeLocation(200,200);
                    }
                });
```

Like I said, it works but I want it more faster. For example, in this case moving time is 2 second, How can I make it 0,5 second ?
Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Use a ValueAnimator (or ObjectAnimator)

Comment: What object should I give to object Animator ? My dot is just a shape. Should I convert it into a drawable or something like that ?

Comment: What object?  "this",  your custom View

Comment: My custom ImageView covers whole screen. My dot is just a shape which is drawn on that ImageView's onDraw method. So I need to move only dot shape (circle). not whole ImageView. Am I wrong ?

Comment: no, you are right, you need to move dot only

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to surfaceview or even faster textureview, both use a canvas as well, and have better performance. Textureview especially as it is hardware accelerated and I also feel it behaves better than surfaceview. That or even consider going to GLSurfaceView.

You can see some example code of surfaceview and textureview: [Here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/2d-animation-for-android-seriescomparing-and-contrasting-different-ways-of-doing-the-same)